# switch between video streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, http-streaming, sharpffmpeg

I am struggling with switching between multiple live streams. For example, I have five live streaming servers streaming(HTTP or RTSP) and I want to put some broker between those (five) streaming sources and destination so that output to the destination would be one video streaming (later I may change the streaming source again using switch). Broker plays role of switcher, My question is, is there such open source "switcher"? Or how this technology works?

here is link to similar question but I want some open source or some brief guidance about how it could be implemented: http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/117/858680

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

**That answer can be an archive for the researchers**

---

**First Suggestion or Solution(Multicast Router)**

---

You can use a Router or L3 Switch which is support IGMP protocol. That Router or L3 Switch must support IGMP protocol you can structure multicast IP address. You can configure L3 to switch all streaming. Multicast Ip address works within  224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255 and works based on device' mac address. You can create different multicast Ip address for the different type of switching scenarios. After finished Router or L3 Switch configuration, you only change IP address to switch streaming into your program. (I didn't mention Broadcast. Broadcast send data to all points. Multicast send data to certain points.)

[image: A sample of Multicast]

---

**Second Suggestion or Solution(Programming)**

I am using **Vlc.Dotnet** wrapper for using the Vlc and libvlc libraries. It's open source. RTSP streaming is based on IP address and port number. I don't know any open source switch but you can write one of them for you with use Vlc.dotnet wrapper. You build 5 Streaming server and 1 control server. The Streaming Server's destination should be Control Server's IP. and you can control all data from control server with your basic switch program.

5 Streaming Servers : Sends data to Control server
1 Control Server    : Controls and Switches data

---

I prefer to use Router or L3 Switch for make that. Because it's easier.